# How to limit the number of entries in django database ? Using the default database (sqlite3)

Tags: python, django

How can i specify number of entries in my django database (sqlite3). For example my model is:

```
from django.db import models

class About(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    details = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'About'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

Now i want to store data of only 2 members in my database. And after adding the data of both users in database from django admin panel, if i try to store data of 3rd member than it should show that database limit is crossed you can't store this data, delete previous data first.
Is it possible to limit entries form django models.py .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `ModelAdmin` and put your logic there, so if you edit your `admin.py` for the app that your `About` model is in to be something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.contrib import messages

from .models import About

class AboutAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if self.model.objects.count() >= 2:
            self.message_user(request, 'Only two entries can exist at once - please remove others first', messages.ERROR)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(f'admin:{self.model._meta.app_label}_about_changelist'))
        return super().add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

admin.site.register(About, AboutAdmin)
```

That should do the trick...

Answer (score 2):

Write a user defined exception

```
class DbLimitException(BaseException):
      pass
```

Override the `save` method of class `About`

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    total_records = About.objects.count()
    if total_records >= 2:
       raise DbLimitException({"message": "Db limit reached please delete to add more data"})
    else:
       super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: i got an error, " DbLimitException " is not defined

Comment: You have to import it from the file you have defined it did you define it first?

Comment: So how it will work? Your error is straight forward `DbLimitException is not defined`. Define it in a file and import **OR** define it same file above `About`  model

Comment: i am not able to modify the daat of those 2 existed users because of this logic.

Comment: it's because of overriding the save function

Comment: Just modify if condition to verify if the count is 2 and the object that you are trying to save doesn't have a pk `total_records == 2 and self.pk is None`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is this,

view.py

```
about_count = About.objects.count()
if about_count == 2:
    return render(request, template_name="template.html", context={"error": "You cannot add more entries to the table, you need to delete the previous ones"}
```

template.html

```
{% if error %}
   {{error}}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: i need a solution for admin panel

Comment: Yes, I realized that later, but didn't think of modifying my answer as @Yugandhar Chaudhari has already answered this perfectly.

Comment: but with that logic i am not able to modify the existed data because of overriding the save function